# Check if form element sent but empty with PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, isset

I'd like to separate two things.

If a `$_POST["something"]` was sent, BUT empty.

OR

If a `$_POST["something"]` was not sent.

Is there a way?

Comment: How do you know if an array HAS a certain key or does not have it?

Comment: If a field is empty, it won't appear in the POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be tempted to use `empty()`, but it blows up in your face if your possible values include a `0`.  Best to use something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['something'])) {
   // the form field was sent ...
   if ($_POST['something'] === '') {
      // the form field was sent, but is empty
   }
}
```

This works, as ALL data coming out of the _GET/_POST/_REQUEST superglobals is a string, regardless of whether it's a number or not.

Comment: I advise against using `===''` and for using `strlen()`

Comment: While, in this specific scenario, there may be virtually no difference, it is a better practice to check for a zero-length string based on exactly that - its length and not its content.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `isset()`

```
if (isset($_POST["something"])){
    echo "The Post Variable 'something' was posted";
    if (strlen($_POST["something"])==0)
        echo "The Post Variable is blank";
    else
        echo "The Post Variable Contains ".$_POST['something'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

look towards `isset` and `empty`.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php

Edit : The comments below are true. Empty should be used for empty strings, not numeric values, float values or a zero in a string​​. However, here's a function if you need to accept these as valid values:

```
function is_blank($value) {
    return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
}
```

Comment: `empty()` will not work if the post variable is set to "0" or several other values, according to your link.

Comment: empty blows up if your possible data includes a `0`. `0 == ''` is TRUE, as is `$x = 0; empty($x);`

Answer (score 0):

i use the php function isset() to check if a POST was sent or not

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score -1):

if ($_POST["something"]) 
will return true if there is such field

if $_POST["something"] == "" 
will do the rest

Comment: Unreliable: `'' == 0` evalutes to TRUE. 0 might be a valid value, and blindly using $_POST['something'] when it isn't set will issue warnings.